# why react-context is returning undefined when no value has been passed from provider, rather than returning a default value?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have created react context object **with a default value** 
like that :

```
const Mycontext = React.createContext("green");
```

and expected when **no value** passed to `Proivder`

the `Consumer` will **get the defualt value** I passesed it but rather than it return `undefined`

please take a look at this simple example on [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-ex-111-lhsxz) and tell me what is my wrong

Comment: The defaultValue argument is only used when a component does not have a matching Provider above it in the tree. Since you have a provider, it won't use the default. https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html#reactcreatecontext see the second paragraph.

Comment: @DennisMartinez Thanks a lot ... can you add it as answer plz

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> The defaultValue argument is only used when a component does not have
>   a matching Provider above it in the tree.

Found in paragraph 2 here https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html#reactcreatecontext

Since you have a provider, regardless of the provider having a value or not, the context won't use the default. If the context can't find a provider, it'll fallback to the default.

```
const MyContext = createContext("I'm the default value")

function MyProvider(props) {
  return <MyContext.Provider {...props} />
}

function MyConsumer() {
  return (
    <MyContext.Consumer>{(value) => console.log(value)}</MyContext.Consumer>
  )
}

// Should not use the default from createContext since there is a valid provider.
function AppWithProvider() {
  return (
    <MyProvider>
      <MyConsumer />
    </MyProvider>
  )
}

// Should use the default from createContext since there is no provider.
function AppWithoutProvider() {
  return <MyConsumer />
}
```

Check it out here https://codesandbox.io/s/condescending-taussig-6n7tq.